# What's the best way to make my java service run in a distributed environment, which uses Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-spark, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have a gRPC java service which uses Hibernate for making database updates. The data ingestion part takes a long time, and I need to ingest even more data which would make it impossible to do it sequentially. I'd like to make the service run in a distributed environment so I can parallelize the data processing.

However, I'm not an expert in Hibernate and I'm wondering if it's possible to make the service distributed as it is, and how to do that. I have used Spark before, but I'm wondering if I want to use Spark for this purpose I'd have to essentially rewrite the entire service. Is there an easier way to do it?

What my service does:

- supports backend API endpoints via gRPC
- ingests data by reading inputs from AWS S3, comparing the incoming data with the current database and makes updates where necessary, using Hibernate

Comment: If you have a lot of data, I would recommend going directly to the database to feed it directly, instead of going through Hibernate. If you really have to go through the app, look up batch size in hibernate which you might be able to tune it up for what you are doing.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

or

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Comment: would recommend subscribing to S3 events rather than polling S3: slow and expensive.